# CSS variables - How to use multiple variables on the same property?

Tags: svg, css-variables

Using CSS variables, we can use the following:

```
style="
  opacity:var(--SOMETHING, 1)
  ">
```

But, how to use multiple such variables, for the same property (e.g. `opacity`), as in the not-working:

```
style="
  opacity:var(--SOMETHING, 1);
  opacity:var(--ANOTHERTHING, 1)
  ">
```

In fact, because I am using SVGs, in my particular use-case, I can solve this by using the working:

```
style="
  opacity:var(--SOMETHING, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--ANOTHERTHING, 1)
  ">
```

But this will ONLY solve it because we used two variables only. For three variables, this hack stops being possible. How to make the following work?

```
style="
  opacity:var(--SOMETHING, 1);
  opacity:var(--ANOTHERTHING, 1);
  opacity:var(--YETSOMETHINGELSE, 1)
  ">
```

Here's a **MWE** code snippet:

```css
.HIDDEN_LAYER{
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
}
.CLICKME_TICKBOX{
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
}
.CLICKED_TICKBOX{
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
}
.CLICKME_TEXTS{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
}
.CLICKED_TEXTS{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  stroke:black;
  stroke-width:0.5;
}
.BOTTOM-LAYER_RECTANGLES{
  fill:white;
  stroke:black;
}
.ZZZ_RECTANGLES{
  visibility:hidden;
  cursor:help;
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:black;
  --QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.7;
  --QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB: 0.2;
}
.FFF_RECTANGLES{
  visibility:hidden;
  cursor:help;
  fill:red;
  stroke:black;
  --PPP_SOMETHING_AAA: 0.2;
  --PPP_SOMETHING_BBB: 0.7;
}
.LEGENDBOX_ZZZ{
  fill:yellow;
  stroke:black;
}
.LEGENDBOX_FFF{
  fill:red;
  stroke:black;
}
.LEGENDS{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg id="SVG"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="1320"
  height="1125"
  viewBox="-15 -45 1350 1155">

<symbol id="SOMETHING_AAA">
<use
  xlink:href="#RECTANGLE"
  transform="translate(637.5, 25)"
  style="
  opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_AAA, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--PPP_SOMETHING_AAA, 1)
  ">
</use>
</symbol>
<symbol id="SOMETHING_BBB">
<use
  xlink:href="#RECTANGLE"
  transform="translate(15, 215)"
  style="
  opacity:var(--QQQ_SOMETHING_BBB, 1);
  fill-opacity:var(--PPP_SOMETHING_BBB, 1)
  ">
</use>
</symbol>

<g class="BOTTOM-LAYER_RECTANGLES">
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_AAA" />
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_BBB" />
</g>

<g class="ZZZ_RECTANGLES">
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_AAA">
<title>Something here 111.</title>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_BBB">
<title>Something here 222.</title>
</use>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
</g>

<g class="FFF_RECTANGLES">
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_AAA">
<title>Something here 333.</title>
</use>
<use xlink:href="#SOMETHING_BBB">
<title>Something here 444.</title>
</use>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
</g>

<g id="LEGENDS"
  class="LEGENDS"
  transform="translate(15, -15)">

<g id="ZZZ">
<g id="CLICKME_ZZZ">
<rect id="CLICKME_TICKBOX_ZZZ"
  class="CLICKME_TICKBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="15"
  height="15">
</rect>
<use id="CLICKME_LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  class="LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKME_TEXT_ZZZ"
  class="CLICKME_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
</g>
<g id="CLICKED_ZZZ"
  class="HIDDEN_LAYER">
<use id="CLICKED_TICKBOX_ZZZ"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  xlink:href="#CLICKED_TICKBOX">
</use>
<use id="CLICKED_LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  class="LEGENDBOX_ZZZ"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKED_TEXT_ZZZ"
  class="CLICKED_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_ZZZ.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_ZZZ.click" />
</g>
<animate id="ZZZ_ANIMATE"
  fill="freeze"
  dur="3s"
  keyTimes="0;1"
  values="0;1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity" />
</g>

<g id="DDD"
   transform="translate(0,40)">
<g id="CLICKME_DDD">
<rect id="CLICKME_TICKBOX_FFF"
  class="CLICKME_TICKBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="15"
  height="15">
</rect>
<use id="CLICKME_LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  class="LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKME_TEXT_FFF"
  class="CLICKME_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
</g>
<g id="CLICKED_DDD"
  class="HIDDEN_LAYER">
<use id="CLICKED_TICKBOX_FFF"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  xlink:href="#CLICKED_TICKBOX">
</use>
<use id="CLICKED_LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  class="LEGENDBOX_FFF"
  x="30"
  y="-5"
  xlink:href="#LEGENDBOX">
</use>
<text id="CLICKED_TEXT_FFF"
  class="CLICKED_TEXTS"
  x="65"
  y="12.5">
Click me
</text>
<set
  to="visible"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="visibility"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
<set
  to="1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity"
  end="CLICKED_DDD.click;bg.click"
  begin="CLICKME_DDD.click" />
</g>
<animate id="DDD_ANIMATE"
  fill="freeze"
  dur="3s"
  keyTimes="0;1"
  values="0;1"
  attributeType="CSS"
  attributeName="opacity" />
</g>

</g>

<defs id="DEFINITIONS">
<rect id="RECTANGLE"
  width="85"
  height="95">
</rect>
<rect id="RECTANGLE_YELLOW"
  width="42.5"
  height="95">
</rect>
<rect id="LEGENDBOX"
  x="0"
  y="0"
  width="25"
  height="25">
</rect>
<path id="CLICKED_TICKBOX"
  class="CLICKED_TICKBOX"
  d="M 0,0 15,15 M 0,15 15,0 M 0,0 15,0 15,15 0,15 Z"/>
</defs>
```

Note that it is working because, in the MWE, I alternate between "**opacity**:var" and "**fill-opacity**:var". I DO NOT WANT TO DO THAT, I want to use **fill-opacity** ONLY, because there might need to be further instances of the "click me" added.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting it to look like? The syntax you want is illegal but maybe there's another way...

Comment: How would you like the two variables to interact? You can only have one value for opacity at a time. Are you looking to have one variable fall back to the other if unspecified?

Comment: @BoltClock I want it to work like it is working in the MWE (there, it works because I alternate between `fill-opacity` and `opacity`), but instead I would like to use `opacity` only.